# Sub query issue, SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, subquery

Just playing around with subqueries in SQL Server (I know that this problem doesn't have to be done with a subquery, but I want to know where my syntax problems are)

```
select count(*) from 
( select id, totalcharges from tblVisits where (totalcharges <10000))
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: @wootscootinboogie For future reference it's generally a good idea to include any extra info like this as an edit to the question, rather than bury it deep in the comments ;-)

Comment: yeah, i knew better.  took the easy way out like a noob.

Comment: A [derived table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx) as a data source is rather different from a (possibly correlated) [subquery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575(v=sql.105).aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to name your sub-query - e.g. aliasing it to "t" here:

```
select count(*) from 
( select id, totalcharges from tblVisits where (totalcharges <10000)) t
```

Comment: Ah yes. Since the subquery is essentially a derived table, correct?

Comment: Exactly, it needs a reference to it

Comment: learning is FUNdamental :)  just checked..and I don't know if that joke means anything across the pond.